# Need help building MySQL statement with subquery based on a date

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to extract a pretty specific set of results from our ticketing system.  First, the part that works... this query successfully grabs all new and open tickets for a group of clients.

```
SELECT COUNT(tickets.ticketid)
FROM tickets, mastergroups AS groups, clients 
WHERE clients.clientid = tickets.clientid 
AND clients.name = groups.name 
AND groups.fullname LIKE 'GROUP NAME%' 
AND (tickets.status = 1 or tickets.status = 2);
```

The next part, though, has been kicking my butt quite a bit.  Here is the relevant table information that I need to pull from.

table: ticketdata

```
ticketid int
datatype int
ticketdatadate timestamp
```

table: tickets

```
ticketid int (corresponds with ticketid above)
clientid int (corresponds with clientid in the above query)
```

There are two other tables listed in the above query, but they are only relevant to tickets insofar as the client grouping is concerned.  If you need information about that, I'll provide it, but working with tickets is where I have trouble.

For each ticket that this query returns, I need to find out what the most recent activity on it was, and ultimately the query needs to return a single number equal to a specific datatype.  (Datatypes are recorded numerically in the database, and the relevant one is 2.)  In other words, if the most recent datatype on 3 tickets is 2 and the most recent datatype on 4 other tickets is 1, I need to return 3.

In the past I would have simply queried for the initial list of tickets, and then used PHP to build separate queries to get the results I needed.  Unfortunately (for me, anyway), if this is to be done, it needs to be a pure MySQL implementation.  I'm not exactly new to MySQL, but I've also never really had need for anything much more advanced than the above query, so please be gentle.  I've looked at documentation and examples regarding JOIN clauses, but nothing has clicked thus far.  Heck, I'm not even sure JOIN is what I need....  so I appeal to others - do you have any examples or advice to give here?  Is this even possible to do with a single SQL statement?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

EDIT:
Ok, trying to clarify .... sorry, I'm new around these parts.

The "tickets" table is a master record of all tickets.  There will only ever be one record per ticket ID in there.

An example; my apologies for the formatting:

```
TicketID    ClientID    ProjectID   ComputerID  Status  Subject Time    Priority    UserID  DueDate StartedDate ContactDate UpdateDate  RequestorEmail  CCEmail Level   Category    LocationID  ExternalID  MonitorId   GroupId MobileDeviceId  GUID    DeviceID
79924   11  0   15648   1   subject (redacted)  0   14  0   2014-12-14 07:37:10 2014-12-15 07:37:10 2014-12-15 07:45:02 2014-12-15 07:44:02 email@address  username     1   5   0   0   0   0   0       0
```

The "ticketdata" table, on the other hand, contains an historical record of all activity in the ticket.  It can, therefore, have a number of records associated with each ticket ID.  I believe it has to have at least two records, in fact, as one will be generated when the ticket is first opened, and another when the ticket is closed.  Any client correspondence, document attachments, work performed, etc., will also generate a new record in that table.  Each record has a date associated with it for when that record was created.

```
TicketDataID    TicketID    DataType    Data    Attachment  Address UserID  TicketDataDate
363831  79924   1   Message associated with ticket request (redacted)       email@address  username 0   2014-12-15 07:37:10
363835  79924   22  Second message associated with ticket request (redacted)        user    0   2014-12-15 07:44:02
```

So, with that said, I need a count of unique tickets.  The tickets table needs to be included because it contains the reference to the client IDs that I need.  However, the ticketdata table contains the datetime value I need to draw from, but only if the most recent record for a given ticket has a DataType equal to 2.

Hopefully I didn't just muddy the waters further.

Comment: I am not clear on  what you are trying to do.  Can you clarify " (Datatypes are recorded numerically in the database, and the relevant one is 2.) In other words, if the most recent datatype on 3 tickets is 2 and the most recent datatype on 4 other tickets is 1, I need to return 3. (Datatypes are recorded numerically in the database, and the relevant one is 2.) In other words, if the most recent datatype on 3 tickets is 2 and the most recent datatype on 4 other tickets is 1, I need to return 3."

Comment: I'll try, anyway.  Datatype in this context is just the name of the field; that alone might help somewhat.  Essentially, the final value needs to be, "A count of all tickets where the most recent value of the datatype field is equal to 2."

Comment: Can a ticket_id have more then one most recent tciketdatedate?  I am trying to determine if you want  the count of tickets per ticket_id or overall the tickets

Comment: I agree your description is somewhat cloudy.  Edit your question and show some sample data referring to the tickets, sample dates / status to show the "most recent" for consideration and what you would like to see as an expected result with such sample data you make available... even if 6-10 record samples.